# Is it possible to have syntax on only for active buffer in vim?

Tags: vim

syntax on/off affects all buffers.

To set buffer specific syntax highlighting,

```
:syntax manual
:set syntax=ON/OFF
```

Before writing a adhoc script that does tracking active buffer and applying syntax=ON only on it, I thought it is better to ask here if there is already a vimcommand doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dirty and quick

use autocmd, when `BufEnter`, `setlocal syntax=on`; when `BufLeave` `setlocal syntax=off.`

Note, You should use `setlocal`, not `set`